# Integrating PKRevealController with Storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am looking to integrate PKRevealController and to provide an overall sliding settings menu for my app. 
I couldn't find any tutorials on doing it with storyboards. I already have a storyboad that hosts a navigationcontroller ( the one that comes by default ) with an arrow pointing to the rootviewcontroller ( called in my case LoginViewController).

Following whatever documentation for the PKRevealController I added a separate Viewcontroller scene and made its class a PKRevealController, and then did this in the app delegate

```
@interface AhmAppDelegate() <PKRevealing>
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) PKRevealController *revealController;
@end 

@implementation AmAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary    
*)launchOptions
{

self.revealController = (PKRevealController *)self.window.rootViewController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.revealController;
LoginViewController *frontViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Mainview_iPad" 
 bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[self.revealController setFrontViewController:frontViewController];//This throws the error

return YES;

}
```

When running this I get the following error

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
    '-[UINavigationController setFrontViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
   0xb17aec0'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eddie,

I was getting a similar issue and thought it was because of my storyboards. However on closer inspection, the line that crashes is trying to access `.revealController` on the `UIViewController`

`.revealController` has been implemented via a category on `UIViewController` and I remembered that you cannot load categories from static libraries without adding a linker flag.

In the installation instructions it says to add the linker flag `-ObjC`, to do so goto your projects `Build Settings` and search for `Other Linker Flags` then add `-ObjC`.

I wasn't using this flag due to another library that I use, it meant it was trying to load other libraries that I didn't wish to include. To get around this issue, I specifically asked it to load just the PKReveal library:

```
-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libPKRevealController.a
```

Hope this will help others as it took me a while :/

W